# How to get rid of checkbox text in subitems ObjectListView

Tags: c#, objectlistview

I've created an [`ObjectListView`](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html) which has sub items with `CheckBoxes`. It's quite simple but the problem is for some reason it keeps on displaying True/False value next to checkbox. I could hide it with setting width 23-30. It's like it's using the true/false value from database but instead of just using it for checkbox it's also displaying it.

[image: ObjectListView]

So any way to get rid of it?

Comment: have you check on the sub-item checkboxes 
`http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/recipes.html#id1` . you might need to set 'UseSubItemCheckBoxes'

Comment: Ye i did check that and that's why you can see the checkboxes in Subitems.. but the thing is it's not hiding text.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To fix that one has to set `OwnerDraw` to `True` on an `ObjectListView`. Took me a while to figure out.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is already been answered, but alternatively you can do the following (especially if you dont want OwnerDraw = True):

```
column.AspectToStringConverter = delegate (object o)
{
  return string.Empty;
};
```

This will display empty string as the text.

Comment: Might come in useful some day.

Answer (score 4):

I also had the same problem. I was creating the columns in code but was setting the OwnerDrawn property to true in the designer. When I added UseSubItemCheckBoxes = true and OwnerDraw = true after the column definitions it behaved as expected, including aligning the check box.